# router links are disabled in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular13

I am using Angular CLI 13.3.3

**Issue details**

Router Links are not working. It seems disabled. Not even clickable.

**Video of Issue**

[Issue described in video. Please click here](https://dropbox.com/s/gn1xqk6524mj4uu/Issue%20details.webm?dl=0)

**Rendered Html in Browser**

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="user-role-management">Users</a>
```

**app.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AnnonymousbaseComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NgbModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<header></header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

**App Routing Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import {UsermanagementComponent} from './usermanagement/usermanagement.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        component: UsermanagementComponent,
        path: 'user-role-management'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }), CommonModule],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Am I missing anything? if you need more information, please do let me know.

**Edit - 1**

### **This specific issue is coming in the navbar only.**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular CLI </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="register">Register</a>
                </li>               
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="">Login</a>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if there is an element laying over the top of the link. Do some extensive element inspections maybe?

Comment: already done, no such surprises there. I can confirm.

Comment: here is the video to explain issue in further details: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gn1xqk6524mj4uu/Issue%20details.webm?dl=0

Comment: maybe try replacing the <a> tag with something different like a <span>

Comment: span not working, would you like to join me on team viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `[routerLink]` directive. Make sure that `declarations` in `app.module.ts` contains the components you want to use the `[routerLink]` in. Also you might have to import `RouterModule` in `app.module.ts`?! I made a quick [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bpfabj?file=src/app/app.module.ts) example for this.

I don't know why these components aren't automatically put inside `declarations` when generating them but that should fix the problem and make the Links clickable.

These are the links in `list.component.html`:

```js
<ul>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['/details', '1']">Product 1</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['/details', 2]">Product 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is `app.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; // This was the missing import.
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: ListComponent },
      { path: 'details/:id', component: DetailsComponent },
    ]),
    RouterModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, ListComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: would you like to join me remotely?

Comment: Yeah sure. I've got a bit of time

Comment: team viewer? 344 149 783

Comment: Yeah, just need the password

Comment: jirk25qu - this is the code

Comment: can you please highlight this line of code as this was the only missing part: `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';`